# HTML5 Videos Not Loading in Deployed App

Tags: html, video, heroku, asset-pipeline, middleman

I am currently making a static site that makes use of a .mp4 video. I am using Middleman and hosting with Heroku (free plan). On my local server everything works wonderfully, but in the deployed Heroku version the video appears as a black box. In Safari and Firefox there is no container at all. All my other assets seem to be loading nicely (including a 4.2mb audio file). The video is 5.9 mb. In the Chrome inspector the video has a status of 206 Partial Content. Any idea what is going on here? Thank you in advance!!

```
<video class="vid-home" src="/videos/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bother with Heroku if you're using Middleman? Seems to me you may as well publish the whole thing to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so looks like my static assets were probably too big. I set my assets up to be served with Amazon S3 and it's working like a dream!